# Reference paths Not being Used in MSBuild XML

Tags: xml, properties, reference, msbuild, path

Hello all:   Searched all over and couldn't find an answer, I'm a newb so please bear with me.  I have an MSBuild xml file, which should clear all projects' bin and obj folders before the build.  As well, this build file sets up (or should) reference paths to be used when compiling the projects.  The problem I'm having is when the build clears the bin and obj folders, none of the projects are compiling using the reference path PropertyGroup.  A sample of the reference paths being set, as well as one project's compile:

REFERENCE PATHS:

```
<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="GetLatest;CleanBinObj;CleanNetDLL">
    <!-- Compile DLLs and Copy them to the Build Folder -->
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ThirdPartyAtalasoftDLLReferencePath>E:\Builds\Third Party\Atalasoft\10.0 - .NET 4.0\</ThirdPartyAtalasoftDLLReferencePath>
      <ThirdPartyHylandDLLReferencePath>E:\Builds\Third Party\Hyland\</ThirdPartyHylandDLLReferencePath>
      <ThirdPartyInfragisticsDLLReferencePath>E:\Builds\Third Party\Infragistics\12.1\</ThirdPartyInfragisticsDLLReferencePath>
      <ThirdPartyMSOfficeDLLReferencePath>E:\Builds\Third Party\MS Office\</ThirdPartyMSOfficeDLLReferencePath>
      <ThirdPartyMSSQLDLLReferencePath>E:\Builds\Third Party\MS SQL CE\</ThirdPartyMSSQLDLLReferencePath>
      <ThirdPartyOtherDLLReferencePath>E:\Builds\Third Party\Other\</ThirdPartyOtherDLLReferencePath>

      <ApplicationDLLBuildPath>E:\Builds\NetDLL\$(CodeBranch)\Applications\</ApplicationDLLBuildPath>
      <MiddlewareDLLBuildPath>E:\Builds\NetDLL\$(CodeBranch)\Middleware\</MiddlewareDLLBuildPath>
      <ComponentDLLBuildPath>E:\Builds\NetDLL\$(CodeBranch)\Components\</ComponentDLLBuildPath>
      <InterfaceDLLBuildPath>E:\Builds\NetDLL\$(CodeBranch)\Interfaces\</InterfaceDLLBuildPath>
      <TriggerProcessDLLBuildPath>E:\Builds\NetDLL\$(CodeBranch)\Trigger Process\</TriggerProcessDLLBuildPath>
      <WebOutPutBuildPath>E:\Builds\NetDLL\$(CodeBranch)\Web\</WebOutPutBuildPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ReferencePath>
        $(MiddlewareDLLBuildPath);
        $(ComponentDLLBuildPath);
        $(InterfaceDLLBuildPath);
        $(ThirdPartyAtalasoftDLLReferencePath);
        $(ThirdPartyHylandDLLReferencePath);
        $(ThirdPartyInfragisticsDLLReferencePath);
        $(ThirdPartyMSOfficeDLLReferencePath);
        $(ThirdPartyMSSQLDLLReferencePath);
        $(ThirdPartyOtherDLLReferencePath)
      </ReferencePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

PROJECT COMPILE:

```
<MSBuild Projects="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
             Properties="ReferencePath=$(ReferencePath)"></MSBuild>
```

Everything seems correct to me here.  If any more code is needed to solve this please let me know.